# Access VBA Spell Check One Field of a Subform

Tags: vba, ms-access, spell-checking, subform

I am trying to make a memo field be spell checked when it leaves the field, and when it leaves the subform to the main form. I want to have this done automatically without having a click button, as I need the data to be as accurate and error-free as possible.

In the main form I have used this code to spell check a title field once you move off the field.

```
Private Sub DetailedTitle_Exit(Cancel As Integer)

'This code works to spellcheck the title after leaving.

With Me!DetailedTitle
    If Len(.Value) > 0 Then
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        .SelStart = 1
        .SelLength = Len(.Value)
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSpelling
        .SelLength = 0
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

This works well, as users will 99% of the time moving from this field to another field in the main form. This does not work when I use in on the subform even when I use the on exit field event AND the on exit subform event. It seems to work, but if you click around it will actually give an error. I wasn't smart enough to note the error, and I have since removed the code.

I would also not be opposed if I could get it to loop thought the subform, as it is a continuous form, but only that one field.

Any advice or tips would be welcome. I just recently learned of the Do.Cmd.RunCommand acCmdSpelling, but there seems to be a lack of content in regards to subforms. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/run-the-spell-check-through-code.1636292/

One user mentions that the control you want to check has to be in focus.

```
Sub subformMemo_OnExit()
  Me.subformMemo.setfocus
  DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSpelling
End Sub
```

On the other hand this code creates the problem that you cannot leave the control because you will always setfocus on it again.

Does this help?